# 0.8.42/Error with Dates

Tags: breeze

there themes to be a problem with reading null dates on Entities. (could not find out if actually only for null values or in general till now)

This method seems to be the problem (not sure): (breeze.debug.js, l. 610)

```
function isDate(o) {
    return classof(o) === "date" && !isNaN(o.getTime());
}
```

o does not have a method `getTime()` here. I could not track the problem down any further. Due to promises stepping through the code does not work well.

**EDIT: ** I updated from 0.8.34, where it is still working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug involving local entity queries for null dates.  It has been fixed in v 0.84.3 and is now available [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download).

Thanks Sascha!

Comment: While further testing and loading entities remotely i could not reproduce the error either. Then i noticed that the problem only occurs with a local query. I preload a set of entities and query one of those locally with a predicate checking for a null value at the date-field. `new breeze.Predicate("ClosedAt", Qop.Equals, null);`
I will try to produce an example tomorrow.